# Adding ListItem via CSOM trigger both Create and Update Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow, csom

I'm using CSOM to create listitems in a custom list on SharePoint 2013.
On the list I have 2 workflows, one that executes on item create and one that executes on item change. Or "Start workflow automatically when an item is created" on the one and "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" in SPD.

The CSOM insert the listitem correctly, but the "Add" workflow does not execute as expected. It turns out that both the workflows get triggered and they immediately suspend with HTTP 500 errors:

> HTTP 500 Object reference not set to an instance of an object. >{"SPRequestGuid":["a352a1f0-76a6-1706-bfca-8d197c091631"],"request-id":["a352a1f0-76a6-1706-bfca-8d197c091631"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"SPRequestDuration":["7131"],"SPIisLatency":["2"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4675"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],

I need to find a way that the CSOM insert only trigger the "Add" workflow.
Any ideas what the issue here can be and how to go about getting it to function as expected?